# How Do I Configure a WCF Service to Be Called Via Cross-Domain AJAX

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json, wcf

I'm having a little difficulty configuring my WCF service to allow consumption via cross-domain AJAX.

I've successfully used this service on a client with no problems, but everytime I try to hit it using AJAX (via the $.ajax object in jQuery), I get a 400 error.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="basicHttpBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <mexHttpBinding>
                <binding name="mexHttpBinding" />
            </mexHttpBinding>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="Services.WebAnalyticsService">
                <clear />
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"
                 name="WebAnalyticsDotNetClientEndpoint" contract="Contracts.IWebAnalyticsService"
                 listenUriMode="Explicit" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding"
                 name="WebAnalyticsMetaDataEndpoint" contract="Contracts.IWebAnalyticsService"
                 listenUriMode="Explicit" />
                <endpoint address="script" behaviorConfiguration="aspNetAjaxBehavior"
                 binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
                 name="WebAnalyticsAjaxEndpoint" contract="Contracts.IWebAnalyticsService" />
                <!--<endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior"
                 binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
                 name="WebAnalyticsAjaxEndpoint" contract="Contracts.IWebAnalyticsServiceWeb"  />-->
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="aspNetAjaxBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
                <!--<behavior name="RESTBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>-->
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
        <system.diagnostics>
            <sources>
                <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
                    <listeners>
                        <add name="xml"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
                    </listeners>
                </source>
            </sources>
        </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And this is my operation contract.

```
Namespace Contracts

        <ServiceContract()>
 Public Interface IWebAnalyticsService

    <OperationContract(), WebGet(RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Sub SendWaEvent(ByVal eventID As Integer, ByVal eventValue As String, _
      ByVal cookieVisitID As String, ByVal cookieVisitorSession As String, _
      ByVal HTTPXForwardedServer As String, ByVal HTTPXRewriteURL As String, _
      ByVal ScriptName As String, ByVal ServerName As String)

    End Interface

End Namespace
```

My Ajax call is pretty straightforward, but here it is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  crossDomain: true,
  url: 'http://localhost:37490/services/webanalyticservice.svc/SendWaEvent',
  data: Data, //Data is a JSON wrapper I've previously constructed.
  contentType: 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8'
  success: function(result) {DoSomething(result);},
  error: HandleError
});
```

[**UPDATES BELOW**]

It's always the things we overlook, isn't it? Anyhow, after being very dismissive of the "straightforward" AJAX call above, it ended up being the problem. To get this working, I had to change my AJAX call to this:

```
        function SendAJAX() {
            $.ajax({ type: "GET",
                url: URL,
                data: Data,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'MyCallBack',
                timeout: 10000,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { WriteSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { WriteError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) { }
            });
        }
```

Also, please note that if you are going to be testing locally, you'll need to add the following to your web config or you'll receive a 500 error saying that cross-domain javascript isn't allowed in authenticated services.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

You can remove this attribute in your web.release.config using `xdt:transform`.

Huge shout out to @Rajesh! Great job, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery function needs to looks as shown below:

```
function TestingWCFRestWithJsonp() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:37490/services/webanalyticservice.svc/script/SendWaEvent",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    type: "GET",
                    timeout: 10000,
                    jsonpCallback: "MyCallback",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {    
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    }
                });
            }
            function MyCallback(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
```

Since your endpoint element has the address value set you would need to append that to the end of .svc and then provide the method name as in the sample below.

The crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled property on the binding element identifies if your request has a callback method specified and writes the response back to stream.

NOTE: Test the url from your browser to see if you get a successful response as its a WebGet method

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I can now hit the service (awesome improvement, by the way), but it is returning a 500 error. The server is giving me the following message: Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services. I've got crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled set to true in my web.config. What else am I missing?

Comment: I resolved the 500 error. Since I'm testing this locally for now, I had to add `<authentication mode="None" />` to my web config in order to hit the service. Hopefully, this is the last piece. I'm now getting a 405 error, "Method Not Allowed", but when I call the service right from my browser, it works as expected. Any thoughts on this while I go back to Googling?

Comment: Are you sure that you are performing a GET rather than a POST on the method

Comment: Yes, I'm using the following options:

`function SendAJAX() {
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",
     url: URL,
     data: Data,
     timeout: 10000,
     crossDomain: true,
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { WriteSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { WriteError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) },
     complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) { }
    });
   }`

Comment: Again, when I enter the URL into my browser, it works as expected and the operation is successful.

Comment: You sir, are awesome. I totally forgot the 'jsonp' property. It is working now, but would you mind explaining the significance of jsonp in this situation? I'd like to get my head around these concepts.

Comment: I had to add the following to the .svc markup  Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" .....then in .config file <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>